# pyramid project created with pycharm raises a ValueError: Variable assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, pyramid

I'm a newbie to python and I'm trying to work on a web project with the pyramid framework. I use pycharm 4.0.4.
After creating a new pyramid project with pycharm and running setup.py develop, the project generates a ValueError when I try to run it as shown below:

```
C:\Users\Ovurevu\vir1\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.4\helpers\pycharm\pycharm_load_entry_point.py" C:\Users\Ovurevu\Desktop\Python Scripts\Pyramid_one\development.ini
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.4\helpers\pycharm\pycharm_load_entry_point.py", line 8, in <module>
load_entry_point(dist, "console_scripts", name)()
File "C:\Users\Ovurevu\vir1\lib\site-packages\pyramid\scripts\pserve.py", line 58, in main
return command.run()
File "C:\Users\Ovurevu\vir1\lib\site-packages\pyramid\scripts\pserve.py", line 257, in run
vars = self.get_options()
File "C:\Users\Ovurevu\vir1\lib\site-packages\pyramid\scripts\pserve.py", line 197, in get_options
return parse_vars(restvars)
File "C:\Users\Ovurevu\vir1\lib\site-packages\pyramid\scripts\common.py", line 15, in parse_vars
% arg)
ValueError: Variable assignment 'Scripts\\Pyramid_one\\development.ini' invalid (no "=")
```

I have spent a lot of time trying to debug this issue.
What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like development.ini has the problem. Show us that.

Comment: Hard to tell without actually seeing some code... But perhaps there's a line in `development.ini` that should have an `=` in it, but doesn't...?

Comment: I think that there is an issue with how pycharm 4.0.4 sends the pyramid pserve command. I upgraded to pycharm 4.5.1 and I don't have this issue again.

Comment: Can you please add your solution as answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I just had this same error. I figured it out though. There shouldn't be anything wrong with the `development.ini` file.

[image: Settings that resulted in the same error]

Tested functionality via command line. [image: Testing functionality via command line]

I believe it is because anything with a space is not parsed correctly. If you add `"` (quotes) around the path it will work.

[image]

Tested on [image]